# "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated" error

Tags: php

The problem is:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\common.php on line 155
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: step in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\common.php on line 94

This is the link where you can find the code:
http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/3592861/file.html

Comment: The link doesn't work. Paste the relevant code blocks in your post here instead.

Comment: Please: (1) provide a more helpful title; (2) include the relevant lines of code directly in your question; and (3) provide a clear statement of both what is currently happening, and what you would prefer to have happen.

Comment: Should flag this question for deletion as it wont be helpful to other in the future when the code disappears.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
$GLOBALS['fc_config']['bot'] =& new Bot();
```

Should be this:

```
$GLOBALS['fc_config']['bot'] = new Bot();
```

And the notice on line 94:

```
if ( $step > 2 || !isset($step) )
```

That you can probably ignore.  You are checking the value of $step, but you never defined that variable.  However, since you also explicitly check if it `isset` I'm guessing you should be fine.  Might be better to check `isset` first though.

Regardless, these are both minor problems.  Sounds like the real problem might be that you have E_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED and error display enabled on a production server, which would be messing up your page displays with error messages.

Try changing the [error display options in your php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) so those don't display (although you would probably want to leave them on for a development box)

Comment: I will prove it now,hang on & thnx;)

Comment: Thank you so much:))It worked perfectly:)))Thankssssssssssss:)))

Comment: Can you plz help me to the next post I made?

Answer (score 2):

The "Assigning the return value of new by reference" is because this idiom is in your code

```
$foo = &new Bar;
```

Change it to

```
$foo = new Bar;
```

To see why this idiom was used in PHP4, see [this manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.newref.php).

Comment: Thnx,I solved it but I had another problem,see the post below!Thank you so much;)

Answer (score 1):

The NOTICE on line 94 is because...

```
if ( $step > 2 || !isset($step) )
```

Should be:

```
if (!isset($step) || $step > 2 )
```

This is because you always want to check if the variable exists FIRST, and then check any other values.  If $step isn't set, you'll get the NOTCIE you received.

Comment: Thank you so much,the fist worked perfectly:))I'm going to prove the next:)))Plz hang on:)Thank you so muchhhhh:)))

Comment: I have this problem:

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\include_themes.php  on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\include_themes.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\include_themes.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\FlashChat_v607\chat\inc\include_themes.php on line 10


and the link of the code is:

http://www12.zippyshare.com/v/6624883/file.html